# Saving column names

Tags: c#, database

In my C# program I'm using dictionaries to map my model objects to the underlying database access (which I cannot change). The key of these dictionaries is the column name of a table in the database and the value is the value of that column. There strings are currently hard coded and I want to improve this.

An example object could be:

```
public class MyObj : FrameworkObj {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public Dictionary<string, Object> ToDictionary() {
       Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
       dict.add("name_of_id_column", this.Id);
       dict.add("name_of_somevalue_column", this.SomeValue); //SomeValue is part of the FrameworkObj class
       return dict;
   }
}
```

My application exists of multiple different model objects which all do the same thing. I would love to be able to have a generic way of accessing the columns which belong to a class, such as implementing an interface which an enum `DbColumns`. As far as I know, this is not possible because very model object has different database columns.

Another approach would be adding tags to every property which maps to the database but that's also not possible because I don't have access to the source code of the framework which I'm using.

A final approach would be adding properties which provide column names such as `ColId` and `ColSomeValue`, but this still seems dirty as I will be adding a lot of extra properties just to save the column names.

Is adding the properties for every column the only approach I can take in my scenario or is there a better (cleaner) way?

Comment: The mapping from column name to property has to be somewhere.. As long as it's only in one place, I guess that's the best you can do. You can't use reflection, since column name is not derivable from property name (right?).

Comment: Your strings appear very clean to me :)

Comment: @Blogbeard Reflection is indeed not an option as the name can not (always) be derived.